# Convert static navigation list to wordpress loop?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, nav

I have the following nav element in regular html. I would like to convert it to a dynamic loop in wordpress. I have already created the pages in Wordpress. I just want to register the nave menu. The problem is, I have more than one ul tag, so i'm not quite sure how to proceed. Here is the following code:

```
<nav id="footerNav">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Who we Are</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">What we Believe</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Leadership</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">What to Expect</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sermons</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Bible Study</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Announcements</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Directions</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Links</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Can someone tell what php function I would need to write to create the links dynamically in wordpress?

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I use custom navigation menus:
[WordPress Navigation Menus](http://codex.wordpress.org/Navigation_Menus)

This way, I can create different nav menus for different sections of the page, and load them into different sections of the template. It even automatically creates widgets for them.

Comment: That's what I usually do, but the problem is that if I add all the pages to the footer menu in wordpress, it doesn't come out right. I'm styling each ul tag, so I need a way to loop through each of those elements in each ul tag separately. I don't know if that makes sense.

Comment: I'm not really sure what the problem would be - would it make sense to create 4 different navigation menus? If you did that, it would create 4 different UL tags for you to use. What sort of functionality are you trying to create once you've got your UL tags correct?

Comment: I floated each ul tag left. Normally, in wordpress, I would employ the <?php wp_nav_menu(); ?> function. It works great when I want to have say a standard menu with menu children. In this case, I am sectioning off sets of links and setting each set side by side. If I employ the same function, it will register the navs as if I have one nav and ul tag and a tags nested. However, in this case, I have 3 ul tags. I just wanted to find a way for wordpress to loop through each set from the entire list of footer menu.

Comment: I think I understand. I would have a footerNav div, which you have. Then, I would run wp_nav_menu() 4 times, and for each time set the menu_id parameter so that you could have menu_id='col1' for the first one, menu_id='col2', and so on. Then, you could set styles for each based on their position. It'll create the html you have in the question above, but allow you to set individual IDs you can then style.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: A nice array:

```
$uls = array( array('Home', 'Who we are', 'What we believe'),
              array('Leadership', 'What to expect', 'Sermons'),
              ...
            );
```

Assuming you have all your data in a nice array:

```
foreach $uls as $ul {

  echo "<ul>";

  foreach($ul as $li) 
    echo "<li>".$li."</li>";

  echo "</ul>";

}
```

Comment: How do I do that? I'm sorry. this is my first time really ever using wordpress let alone creating my own theme. I do have a background in programming OOP and PHP though.

Comment: Thank you so much. Just a last question? Is there a way to get around hardcoding the links? can I loop through the links from the pages specified in the Admin Menus in Wordpress? I don't want to have to change the array each time I update a link.

Comment: Sorry, don't know anything about wordpress. But if the links are being specified in a database then you could query for them and build up your arrays dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: first of all you have to create a new menu... Appearance>> menu>>add item>> save menu

Step 2: delete your html menu and call the WordPress function

```
<?php wp_nav_menu(array('menu'=> 'mymenu', menu_id=>'footerNav')); ?>
```